# SEQ on Kubernetes not publicly visible

Tags: docker, kubernetes, seq

I'm fairly new to Kubernetes, and I am trying to get SEQ up and running in im the environment. Everything looks like its provisioned correctly, but I can not seem to hit the endpoint. Chrome just spins and eventually says `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

I tried another example from [microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis/blob/master/azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml) and it works correctly. I can hit it from the outside world.

Here is my yaml file:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: seq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  containers:
  - name: seq
    image: datalust/seq:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    - containerPort: 5341
    env:
    - name: ACCEPT_EULA
      value: "Y"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/data"
      name: volume
  volumes:
    - name: volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: azure-managed-disk
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: seq
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: seq
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that your Pod manifest is missing the following in the `metadata` section:

```
labels:
    app: seq
```

It should match what's defined in the Service `selector` section. That's what glues the Service and Pod objects together.

By the way, the statement `replicas: 1` is not part of a Pod manifest but instead used in Deployments to specify how many Pods should be created initially.

To further explain a bit on the topic on how Deployments and Pods usually relates to each other, maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857582/which-names-should-be-same-in-this-k8s-yaml/51865961#51865961), could be a good reference. The same logic applies on how Services and Pods relates to each other and `labels` is an important part of that.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Thanks!